# Div with random values that change with time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a div in an HTML page and write random value in it, then, I want the div to refresh itself every X seconds so that the number in it change, but the entire page is not reloaded, just the div.

My idea was that :

```
<body>
 <div id="people" onload="rand();"> </div>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
     function autoRefresh_div()
     {
      $("#people").load("load.html");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
     }

     setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 0.5); // refresh div after 5 secs

    function rand(){
     document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = Math.random();
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing appear in my div. I tried to change "Math.random()" with some text but nothings change.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Nothing apparently ever calls `rand()`

Comment: Also the time argument to `setInterval()` should be a number of **milliseconds**, not seconds. A 5 second delay would mean you'd pass 5000.

Comment: a `<div>` has no onload event

Comment: What is the point of `$("#people").load("load.html")` if you actually want to display a random number in `#people`?

Comment: Pointy & charlietfl I thought, i'm not really aware with HTML, and I didn't read anything saying that. But now i'll know, thanks,
Turnip It was a way I found that some people use to refresh using another file (that is my final goal, but I wanted to make it step by step, I was in a hurry and didn't changed my code)
And for the time, I know setInterval is in milliseconds, but I wanted to try if I can create something "on real time"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `onload` event. Just `setInterval()` with a function which will set a new value in a div:

```js
function autoRefreshDiv() {
  document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = Math.random();
}
setInterval(autoRefreshDiv, 1000);  // Time is set in milliseconds
```

```html
<div id="people"></div>
```

`setInterval` will run the function every X milliseconds.