# auto generate random number in div every 5 seconds jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use a random number like this website "https://yogylove.myshopify.com/" for wordpress website. Number will be change in 5 or 10 seconds automatically

Comment: And the question/problem is? If you're "asking" for a working solution then SO is not the right place.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself to create this.

Comment: [Generate a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527803), [put it in the div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2554149) and [repeat it every x seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138756).

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i have tried some codes from google. But not worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div with random values that change with time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092105/div-with-random-values-that-change-with-time/42092326)

Comment: thank you @Ivar, those numbers showing like "0.1323955413795357". can it be just one number like "1" "2"

Comment: @KaranKcoresys See the first link in my first comment on how you can generate a number in a range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this snipper:

```js
let genRnd = function() {
    var min=0; 
    var max=9;  
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
};

setInterval(
    function() { 
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = genRnd();
    }, 
    500
);
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: @KaranKcoresys Then I highly recommend you upgrade your browser.